# Can't import when Path has spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-import

Python3.7 on OS X 10.14.5

I have a python script that imports a single local module. They are in the same directory, and everything was working fine. It's a pretty simple setup.

I moved everything over to another directory (on the same machine) and local imports stopped working. The only thing I can tell that has changed is the path, which now contains a folder called "My Drive". I believe the spaces in the path are causing the problem with the import.

I've searched the web, and tried many things, but can't seem to get import to work with a folder in the path that contains spaces. Anyone know any solution to this or a resource to try to figure it out?

***I cannot change the folder name.***

EDIT: 
This was the directory structure:

main.py
lab/
--labs.py

I was able to get it working by flattening out the directory structure. However, when using relative imports:
`import lab.labs`
or adding 'lab' to the path:
`os.path.append("./lab")`
import did not work in that location.

Symlinking also works, but that seems like running around python, rather than fixing it within python, and since this is code that will be shared, I don't want a single machine solution.

Comment: Create a symbolic link to "My Drive" with a path that contains no whitespace.  Put that in your PATH.

Comment: Can you post your import statement?

Comment: Or probably some escaping of spaces in LD_LIBRARY_PATH may help.

Comment: @ChrisFNZ: You can't put quotes around `import`ed module names in Python.

Comment: Appending the path with `sys.path.append("My Drive")`or `sys.path.append('"My Drive"')` before importing _might_ work (because `sys,path` is a list of strings that specify the search path for modules).

Comment: The symbolic link approach didn't work, however, flattening out the directory structure did. I shouldn't have to do that, but at least it works now.